# What is the meaning of value of Position column in Google Search Analytics?

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

In [Google Webmasters Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) left panel **Search Traffic > Search Analytics**,
mark **Position** and **Queries**. Then the table will contain columns **queries** (perhaps keywords) and **Positons**.

What is the meaning of the value of the position column?

[image]

What I think is that these are keywords on the **Queries** column and position of the keywords with respect to my other keywords. But I'm getting better ranking of a keyword with less position value than others.

Answer (score 1):

[I think this example will clear your doubt](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2012/01/update-to-top-search-queries-data.html).

> Let’s say Nick searched for [bacon] and URLs from your site appeared
>   in positions 3, 6, and 12. Jane also searched for [bacon] and URLs
>   from your site appeared in positions 5 and 9. Previously, we would
>   have averaged all these positions together and shown an Average
>   Position of 7. Going forward, we’ll only average the highest position
>   your site appeared in for each search (3 for Nick’s search and 5 for
>   Jane’s search), for an Average Position of 4.

Extra example - 
If I type laxmi temple in Google India, and I see your site in 1st position, and someone from US type same query and see your site in 3rd position, then [average position](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828?hl=en) will be (1+3)/2 = 2

Here not only GEO (location) affect search position, but user devices (like User agent + Device size), language (like US, UK, IN English) also affect search position, hence Google display the average position on search report.

Also the data displayed in search analytic report is not real time, Google might show you one week older data, so the current average position might not 100% accurate.

> But I'm getting better ranking of a keyword with less position value
>   than others.

It's probably because when you search some query then you see second position while other see your site in 5th or 6th,7th position. So here the average position might be higher than 4+, but the ranking(position) for you is better(here is 2nd).

You can get visitors information like device, user-agent, location etc, and then you can apply same thing in your browser, and search same query, then you will get an idea, on which position your site is ranking for others.